# mmap error : cannot allocate memory. how to allocate enough default sized huge pages as admin?

Tags: memory, memory-management, mmap, ubuntu-20.04, grub

I was compiling and running [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spotify/linux/master/Documentation/vm/map_hugetlb.c) program but received 'mmap error : cannot allocate memory'.
The comment at the top reads

```
/*
 * Example of using hugepage memory in a user application using the mmap
 * system call with MAP_HUGETLB flag.  Before running this program make
 * sure the administrator has allocated enough default sized huge pages
 * to cover the 256 MB allocation.
 *
 * For ia64 architecture, Linux kernel reserves Region number 4 for hugepages.
 * That means the addresses starting with 0x800000... will need to be
 * specified.  Specifying a fixed address is not required on ppc64, i386
 * or x86_64.
 */
```

I want to check `if the administrator has allocated enough default sized huge pages to cover the 256 MB allocation` but I am the system administrator. What should I do? I'm on ubuntu 20.04 x86_64 machine.  ( a side question : Does mmap use heap area?)

ADD : please see my comment (I added a boot command argument and the code works. I temporarily added boot argument in the grub menu.) but I wish I could add a init script so that this takes effect every time the computer boots.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation for huge pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hi, thanks! I've read the document( not to the end) and added 'hugepages=16' in the boot command . I and I had change the LENGTH in the code to 2M. (256M was to big). And the code works! Thanks!

Comment: Kernel command line parameters can be added to `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hi, thanks! I added your method in the answer.

Comment: As for your side question "Does mmap use heap area?". No, `mmap` creates a new region, you can think of it as being positioned between the `heap` and `stack` regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be 2 methods.

1. add `vm.nr_hugepages = 16` in /etc/sysctrl.conf and reboot.
   I've checked this works.
2. (as Nate Eldredge commented) add 'hugepages=16' in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" line (inside quotes) of /etc/default/grub and do update-grub.